# How to export to google base

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have the following profile,  it exports well, except for some things

1. The URL, only show the link to the html file
   product.html instead of www.domain.com/product.html
2. I have about 3000 products but it exports 6000 files, 3000 of them are empty, My guess here is that I had a store before and that store was deleted, I am wondering if maybe it didnt delete the relationship product  and store,  How can I check this? in which tables?
3. The image exports something like this:

   /a/l/al23432.jpg
4. How can I export the product category? the string not the ID?

when it should point to the real file

This is the code

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[9]]></var>
    <var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[simple]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[9]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[id]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[title]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[description]]></map>
        <map name="partsubcategory"><![CDATA[product_type]]></map>
        <map name="url_path"><![CDATA[link]]></map>
        <map name="small_image"><![CDATA[image_link]]></map>
        <map name="condition"><![CDATA[condition]]></map>
        <map name="availability"><![CDATA[availability]]></map>
        <map name="price"><![CDATA[price]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[brand]]></map>
        <map name="gtin1"><![CDATA[gtin]]></map>
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[mpn]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[\t]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">ftp</var>
    <var name="path">/</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[google.txt]]></var>
    <var name="host"><![CDATA[ftp.xxx.net]]></var>
    <var name="file_mode">1</var>
    <var name="user"><![CDATA[xxx]]></var>
    <var name="password"><![CDATA[xxx]]></var>
</action>
```

Comment: I need to add something I just detected, for example I use attribute SKU to fill id and mpn, also I use attribute name to fill title and description.  It only exported MPN but not ID, and it only exported description but not title.

Comment: Luis, What version of magento are you using ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tried this method yet.but there is an app on magento-connect that may help try it. [RetailTower](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rinkarto/extension/6771/feed_manager_version_1_1_2)

Comment: they are setting up the account, which btw they really take a lot of time. I will check tomorrow and let you know about this.